# Magento 2 Order Email Template subTotal tfoot colspan Edit

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, email-templates, order-email, magento2email

[image: Magento 2 Order Email Template subTotal tfoot.]

Where Can I edit the Order Email Template subTotal tfoot ??? I need to edit colspan 2 to 3. please check the image

Comment: file responsible for setting colspan is `vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml`

Comment: In above file `order_totals` block has argument `label_properties`. Yuo need to override above file in custom theme.

Comment: Thanks a lot bro.

Comment: welcome :) , I put my comment as answer so you can accept and up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File responsible for setting colspan is:

> vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml

In above file `order_totals` block has argument `label_properties`. You need to override above file in custom theme.

Create new file at:

> app/design/frontend/{Package}/{theme}/Magento_Sales/layout/sales_email_order_items.xml

With following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>  
        <referenceBlock name="order_totals">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="label_properties" xsi:type="string">colspan="3"</argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```